# fire event based on memory useage in R

Tags: r

I was wondering what a good way to fire an event based on the memory usage in R would be.  Say i'm combining a bunch of files into one master file but the size of the entire master file may be too large to hold in memory.  When I approach the memory limit i'd like to save my current master file and free memory.

```
master <- NULL
partnum <- 1
threshold  <- 0.8
filelist <- list.files(mypath)

for (filename in filelist) 
{
   filedata <- read.csv(filename)
   if (is.null(master)) master <- filedata
   else master <- rbind(master,filedata)
   rm(filedata)

   # test for memory usage here
   # if (usedMemory > availableMemory * threshold)
   # then do the following else go to top of loop

   save(master,file=paste(mypath,partnum,"rData",sep="."))
   master <- NULL
   partnum <- partnum + 1
}
```

What i'd like to do is be able to calculate the amount of memory available on the machine.  That way the event would fire dynamically based on current machine usage.  Say when the script is initiated there is 10GB available on the machine, so clean up when 8GB is used.  However say mid-execution another user starts a program that consumes 5GB, then i'd like to clean up when 4GB is used.

```
> x <- 1:10^9
> memory.size()
[1] 3832.26
> memory.limit()
[1] 16381
> gc()
            used   (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)  max used   (Mb)
Ncells    164953    8.9     350000   18.7    350000   18.7
Vcells 500150216 3815.9  669246830 5106.0 550150069 4197.4
```

At this point on my machine I only have 10GB availble due other processes consuming 2GB

Comment: If you are just concatenating a bunch of csv files, then it will probably be easier and faster just to use `file.append`.

Comment: @Richie: i don't think that would work due to the headers in each file

Comment: Stripping the headers (`lines <- readLines(filein); writeLines(lines[-1], fileout)`) would still be easier than messing around with memory.  I think that you are trying to be too clever.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try `memory.size`. Maybe something like this:

```
# Are we using more than 1 GB?
if (memory.size() > 1000) {
  # Force a garbage collect and check again
  gc()
  if (memory.size() > 1000) {
    # free up memory...
  }
}
```

The call to `memory.size` does not do a garbage collect, so you could either always do it before calling or conditionally as in the example above (garbage collection can take some time).

Comment: any idea how to get the amount of memory available on the machine?  memory.size() reports the size of the R instance.  memory.limit() seems to report the total RAM installed on the machine.  i'd really like to know how much memory is currently available.

Comment: I suppose it would be unhelpful to  suggest using a non-32bitWindows OS :-) (see the comments under `?Memory-limits` )

Comment: @darckeen: Um, `memory.limit() - memory.size()`?

Comment: I *think* `memory.limit` (which is Windows-specific) reports an arbitrary size (that you can change). It seems that on 64-bit systems it "always" reports 8 Gb by default (I could be wrong though).

Comment: ...but @Richie Cotton is right, since R will report out-of-memory when the `memory.limit` is reached. So a separate issue is to initialize `memory.limit` to an appropriate value.

Comment: @Richie: thats installed RAM - RAM used by current R instance, consider that there are other memory consuming processes running on the machine.

Comment: @darckeen: `memory.limit` is the amount that R is allowed to consume, which is normally less than the amount of installed RAM.  You could always call the shell, e.g., `shell("tasklist", intern = TRUE)` on Windows, and parse the result.

Comment: @Richie: That should do the trick, thanks alot.  Any idea on do the same thing on linux?